# Does anyone know what kind of window this is? (Repost with photos)

Tags: hvac

This is a repost, as it’s my first time posting and I was unaware I could attach pictures. I was wondering if anyone knows what kind of windows these are, as I have been trying to install a window AC and cannot figure out how and google doesn’t help as I don’t know the type of window to look up. Any help is appreciated! Thanks so much! [image]
[image]

Just to mention, there is a ~3 inch wood piece between the two sets of windows. 3 panes are sliding, 1 is stationary (back left), and on the back right pane which slides is where my window screen usually is.

Comment: Why make a duplicate post when you can edit the original? Just clutters up the site.

Comment: The other account is unregistered - I'd suggested OP gets them merged. I feel like closing the other as a dupe, might be an option

Comment: Looks like a single pane (probably aluminum) slider, with an aluminum storm window—hard to tell since your pics are so darn dark.  Is that the "kind" you're looking for, or are you asking for a brand/manufacturer?  (Also, you should have been able to simply edit your original post instead of creating a new one.  Looks like you created a new account too...)

Answer (score 0):

The type of window is known as horizontal sliding or a horizontal slider.

It may be impossible to find a way to install a window AC unit in that type of window.  You may need to look into [portable AC units](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Hisense-Hisense-150-SF-Portable-AC/5005373569?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-vf-_-app-_-ggl-_-SS_APP_VF-Hisense_118_Refrigerators-Freezers-_-5005373569-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=CjwKCAjwh8mlBhB_EiwAsztdBMC4EhCoY8gTTFTz-fAsURJTvcV22jZevAjJkGWguiuUHyMZnUaRkBoC4q8QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).

Comment: They used to make window units for those kind of windows. I owned one 30-some years ago. The "inside" part and the "outside" part was connected with a narrow "shaft" between them. The unit was balanced in the window and the window was mostly closed with a "gap filler" like an accordion shade extended up from ithe connecing piece to complete the seal.